# How to redirect to relevant app store if app is not installed on device on Safari?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, safari, deep-linking

Working with deep linking, I have the code snippet below on my web page.

The code works fine on Chrome but on Safari, I just get a message to say it could not find the deep link without redirecting.

On Chrome, it redirects to the relevant store if the app is not found.

> "Safari cannot open the specified address: myapp://

I tried wrapping in a try catch block but to no avail.
Any help is appreciated.

```
setTimeout(function () {
                if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1) { 
                    window.open("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp","_top"); 
                }
                else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") > -1) {
                window.open("https://apps.apple.com/us/app/myapp","_top");
                }
            }, 2000);

            window.location = "myapp://";
```

Comment: Manage to resolve it using Firebase dynamic links: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Comment: How does Firebase dynamic link handle the iOS AppStore redirection part when app is not installed?

Comment: On initial setup, you insert some app store values that are required such as the app ID, store link etc.  then if a user tries to visit a deeplink to your app and it's not installed - it will auto redirect to the app store.  This of course can be disabled but it's default behaviour.